# Как сделать вывод из базы данных всей информации после поиска?

Tags: php, mysql

Происходит поиск и необходимо, чтобы также проходил ещё и вывод из базы данных всей информации, так как нельзя перечислить в строке с `$result` все столбцы и в строке с запросом `$sql`, может необходимо что-то прописать в самом коде, чтобы происходил вывод столбцов `infoin_id, title, img`. И вот ещё какой важный момент, получается так, что даже если вывести только столбец `img`, вместо вывода изображения выводит её имя, к примеру . [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и получается, что можно вывести только один столбец любой, но не всю таблицы, пытался менять запрос и использовать AND, а также убрал название столбца и ввёл только название базы как написано в инструкциях и документации, но не помогло. Также вместо mini_description пытался перечислить как уже указано выше все столбцы -также не помогло. Код не работает, если перечислять, может я не правильно использую синтаксис или язык запросов. Может я неправильный принцип использую и нужно взглянуть глобально на код?

```
<?php

        if (isset($_POST['search']))
        {

            include('include/db.php');
            $db = new db();

            $word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM info_db_5 WHERE mini_description LIKE '%" . $word . "%'";


            $row = $db->select_list($sql);
            if(count($row)) 
            {
                $end_result = '';
                foreach($row as $r)
                {
                    $result = $r['mini_description'];


                    $bold = '<span class="found">' . $word . '</span>';
                    $end_result .= '<div=found_cont_1><li class="found_1"><a>' . str_ireplace($word, $bold, $result) . '</a></li></div>';

                }
                echo $end_result; 
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<li>No results found</li>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Создайте массив и после выведите

Comment: как это лучше сделать, в данной реализации кода, не подскажите?

Comment: Как и в любом варианте (http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php), пишите все что Вам нужно в массив, а после читайте

Comment: спасибо - разберемся

Comment: Да не простая задача оказалась, хоть я и не совсем новичок, но бывает и такие ошибки. Надо в любом случае затащить))).